# Typo3 one page with special javascript or css using PIDinRootline

Tags: typo3

I would like that one page has a more javascript includes then the normal ones.
I used this code:

```
    page=PAGE
page{
headerData{
5=TEXT
5.value=<linkhref="fileadmin/templates/style.css"rel="stylesheet"type="text/css"/>
10=TEXT
10.value=<linkhref="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin+Sketch:bold"rel="stylesheet"type="text/css"/>
20=TEXT
20.value=<scriptsrc="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
40=TEXT
40.value=<scripttype="text/javascript"src="fileadmin/templates/js/easySlider1.7.js"></script>
50=TEXT
50.value=<scripttype="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){$("#slider").easySlider({auto:true,continuous:true,prevId:'prevBtn',prevText:'',nextId:'nextBtn',nextText:'',speed:1000,pause:20000,});});</script>
**[PIDinRootline = 8]**
60=TEXT
60.value=<linkhref="fileadmin/templates/skills/default.css"rel="stylesheet"type="text/css"/>
70=TEXT
70.value=<scriptsrc="fileadmin/templates/skills/raphael.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
80=TEXT
80.value=<scriptsrc="fileadmin/templates/skills/init.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
**[end]**
}
```

But those three are included in every page!

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditions can not be nested in ANY block, so instead:

```
page=PAGE
page{
  headerData{
     5=TEXT
     //...
     [PIDinRootline = 8]
       60=TEXT
     [end]
  }
}
```

You should use it like this:

```
page=PAGE
page{
  headerData{
     5=TEXT
     //...
  }
}

[PIDinRootline = 8]
    page.headerData.60=TEXT
[end]
```

Of course I assume that asterisks in your sample `**[PIDinRootline = 8]**` - `**[end]**` are accidental - they are not allowed

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[globalVar = TSFE:id =8]
  page.headerData.60 = TEXT
  page.headerData.60.value (
    <link href="fileadmin/templates/skills/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="fileadmin/templates/skills/raphael.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="fileadmin/templates/skills/init.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
)
[global]
```

or even better:

```
[globalVar = TSFE:id =8]
    page.includeCSS.fonts81 = fileadmin/templates/skills/default.css
    page.includeJS {
        file81 = fileadmin/templates/skills/raphael.js
        file81.type = application/x-javascript
        file82 = fileadmin/templates/skills/init.js
        file82.type = application/x-javascript

    }
[global]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[PIDinRootline=8]
      page.headerData.60 = TEXT
      page.headerData.60.value = <link href="fileadmin/templates/skills/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      page.headerData.70 = TEXT
      page.headerData.70.value = <script src="fileadmin/templates/skills/raphael.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      page.headerData.80 = TEXT
      page.headerData.80.value = <script src="fileadmin/templates/skills/init.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
[END]
```

Thx